# Get 2 words within a string using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get 2 words from a string, where the 2 words can be different each time.

In this example, I'm trying to get `Open` and `On Hold`

```
$str = 'Status Changed from Open to On Hold';
```

I've managed to get `Open` with this code:

```
$starting_word = 'Status Changed from';
$ending_word = 'to';

$subtring_start = strpos($str, $starting_word).strlen($starting_word);
$size = strpos($str, $ending_word, $subtring_start) - $subtring_start; 
$a = substr($str, $subtring_start, $size);
```

And then I tried to get `On Hold` using this, but it's returning nothing.

```
$subtring_start = strpos($str, $a);
$size = strpos($str, '', $subtring_start) - $subtring_start;
$b = substr($str, $subtring_start, $size);
echo $b;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get some good answers on how to do it similar to your approach, but this is easier:

```
preg_match('/ from ([^ ]+) to (.*)/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
echo $matches[2];
```

- match a space and `from` and a space
- capture `()` anything not a space `[^ ]+` up to a space and `to`
- capture `()` anything `.*` to the end

Answer (score 0):

Even though you haven't made clear what the specific dynamic words are, but you can try the following code to get the second string, that is, in your case, `'On Hold'`.

```
$str = 'Status Changed from Open to On Hold';

$starting_word = 'Status Changed from';
$ending_word = 'to';

$size = strpos($str, $ending_word);
$second_value = substr($str, $size+3);
echo $second_value;
```

Output:

```
On Hold
```

Try and change the `'On Hold'` in your `$str` and run the code again, and see the magic.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc2xCsIwEMbxvU9xQ6GKbo5VHFzcOvgAJTaxKdS7I7ko@PLxIgh1cDz4/e9jzznvj@y5qqMEOEBzESMpwskbHJ2FW6A7dOwQhKBDONNsm7Yq3ASZcOyfFOyfUGHt0C6VUKk1n15Obx1liqsyvoWlXWsa3UBo@4eZ08emq7KvLQ82O2Vu8AQ/ts35DQ)